# How to get index of Escape Character in a String?

Tags: java

How to get index of Escape Character  in a String?

```
String test="1234\567890";
System.out.println("Result : "+test.lastIndexOf("\\"));
```

> Result i get: 
>   -1
>
> Result i need: 4

Comment: The backslash **is not in** the string. If you want a backslash in your string, you need to put \\  in your string literal.

Comment: see if i print it, it will print like this 1234.7890

Comment: Your string literal specifies `\56`, which is the `.` character. It does not contain a ``\`` character. You **can** search for the `.` character.

Comment: So the answer would be `test.lastIndexOf("\56")` (or `"."`) which is not helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Your original String doesn't contain `\`. Which means you are searching something which does not exist. Inorder to add `\` to your string. You have to escape while adding

```
String test="1234\\567890";
System.out.println("Result : "+test.lastIndexOf("\\"));
```

Should work.

[image]

In your case look at the last line in the [table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get that because when you use an escape character is for java to interpret the following character in a special way. In another words, the escape character and the next character you see in the string are really one entity from the point of view of program being executed.

When you search for "`\\`", you are searching for the literal character '`\`' not the escape character.

Here you can see the difference: [java fiddle](http://tpcg.io/StjwsG)

While `\5` is the character with code `0x5 (ENQ)`, `5` is the character `0x35`. [See the table](https://ascii.cl/).

Comment: System.out.println("1234\567890"); is getting result as this 1234.7890

Comment: Correct, the slash is giving speacil meaning to the 5. That part of my answer is not correct so I'll change it, but the rest still stands.